# Tkinter DateEntry Calendar Mindate not allowing December month of the same year

Tags: tkinter, tkcalendar, mindate

I am setting the minimum date for selection in calendar to 1st Jan 2022 but I am unable to select any day for the month Dec 2022. All other months are working fine. I observed that if the day is set to any two digit day then there is no issue. ( 2022,1,10 ) works fine and I am able to select Dec 2022 , but ( 2022,1,1) I am not able to select any day of Dec 2022 . Here is the full code:

```py
import tkinter  as tk 
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
from datetime import date
my_w = tk.Tk()
my_w.geometry("320x210")  

dt1=date(2022,1,1) # Minimum date for selection, here is the problem , try to use day as 10** 
dt2=date(2024,5,25) # Maximum date for selection
cal=DateEntry(my_w,selectmode='day', mindate=dt1, maxdate=dt2)
cal.grid(row=1,column=1,padx=15)

my_w.mainloop()
```

Comment: Might be a bug in `tkcalendar`

Comment: It also worked for me first, but I don't know what happened it stopped working. The same code I am using and unable to select Dec 2022.  Try to change the mindate to 2 digit day then it will work again.